# Lumen 8 not using .env.testing

Tags: php, laravel, api, unit-testing, lumen

I'm using Lumen 8.
and I want to use the configuration inside `.env.testing`
but it always read the configuration inside `.env`

***tests/TestCase.php***

```
<?php

use Dotenv\Dotenv;

abstract class TestCase extends Tests\Utilities\UnitTest\Testing\TestCase
{

    public static function setUpBeforeClass(): void
    {
        Dotenv::createImmutable(dirname(__DIR__), '.env.testing')->load();
    
        parent::setUpBeforeClass();
    }
  
    public function createApplication()
    {
        return require __DIR__ . '/../bootstrap/app.php';
    }
}
```

***.env.testing***

```
APP_ENV=testing
APP_DEBUG=false

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db_testing
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=db_testing
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
```

***.env***

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=false

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=db
DB_PORT=3307
DB_DATABASE=db_local
DB_USERNAME=db_username
DB_PASSWORD=db_password
```

when I debug the testing file like
`dd(DB::connection()->getDatabaseName());`
it returns `db_local` instead of `db_testing`

I don't want to add all my configuration inside `phpunit.xml`
what is missing? what should I do?

Comment: are you running artisan with --env=testing ? php artisan --env=testing

Comment: Nope. Is it required? I'm just running my unit testing and I figuring out why my unit testing still used .env.testing instead of .env

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're loading your environment file into a new repository instance, but your lumen application has no idea that repository instance exists.

Next, when your `bootstrap/app.php` file runs, it'll create the repository instance loaded with your normal `.env` file that lumen knows how to use.

The cleanest solution is probably to remove your `setUpBeforeClass()` method and just update your `bootstrap/app.php` file to support loading different .env files.

One example:

```
$env = env('APP_ENV');
$file = '.env.'.$env;

// If the specific environment file doesn't exist, null out the $file variable.
if (!file_exists(dirname(__DIR__).'/'.$file)) {
    $file = null;
}

// Pass in the .env file to load. If no specific environment file
// should be loaded, the $file parameter should be null.
(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__),
    $file
))->bootstrap();
```

If you update your `bootstrap/app.php` file with this code, then you can have one environment variable specified in your `phpunit.xml` file to set the `APP_ENV` variable to `testing`. If you do that, the above code would load the `.env.testing` file.

NB: all theory based on reading code. untested.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite interesting that lumen does not support dynamic enviroment file names after they removed artisan support, Link to the [Issue](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/1055)

So basically you have to go manual mode

In your bootstrap.app file

```
// boostrap.php

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    \dirname(__DIR__),
))->bootstrap();
class LoadEnvironmentVariables
{
    protected $filePath;
    protected $fileName;

    // change the $name, i.e the env file name to your env file manually
    public function __construct($path, $name = null)
    {
        $this->filePath = $path;
        $this->fileName = $name;
    }
  ....
```

Here's another link which might [help](https://github.com/laravel/lumen-framework/issues/1070#issuecomment-650911286)

Answer (score 0):

Simplified version of @patricus answer:

Update your `bootstrap/app.php` with this changes:

```php
$env_file = '.env.' . env('APP_ENV');

(new Laravel\Lumen\Bootstrap\LoadEnvironmentVariables(
    dirname(__DIR__), file_exists(dirname(__DIR__) . '/' . $env_file) ? $env_file : null
))->bootstrap();
```